# Add column for distinct values and count to same tibble in R

Tags: r, count, distinct

I have two tibbles that I would like to combine. They are grouped by the same variable, but I would like to see them in the same table together. The first is:

```
df %>%
    filter(Cancelled == FALSE) %>%
    count(School)
```

Which gives me the count of "School":

| School | count |
| --- | --- |
| Comm | 42 |
| IR | 52 |
| Business | 34 |
| Nursing | 23 |

The next is:

```
df%>%
    filter(Cancelled == FALSE) %>%
    group_by(School) %>%
    summarise(n_distinct(ID))
```

Which gives me the count of unique "ID" values in each "School".:

| School | unique |
| --- | --- |
| Comm | 17 |
| IR | 18 |
| Business | 14 |
| Nursing | 12 |

Basically, what I would like is for the count to be one row and the unique value count to be a second row:

| School | count | unique |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Comm | 17 | 42 |
| IR | 18 | 52 |
| Business | 14 | 34 |
| Nursing | 12 | 23 |

Thank you in advance!

*Edit: better description of original data

```
dput(data)
structure(list(ID = c(1986, 3707, 2467, 3087, 2155, 3133, 2531, 
3112, 2042, 2912, 1305, 1519, 2411, 3630, 2015, 2943, 2873, 1591, 
3127, 3733, 3492, 3156, 3907, 3877, 2050, 2956, 1280, 3544, 1465, 
1410, 3946, 2868, 2288, 3722, 1611, 3188, 3609, 2847, 1803, 2580, 
1928, 1775, 2774, 1259, 3851, 2135, 3046, 1480, 2480, 2240, 3279, 
3983, 2042, 3754, 1851, 3528, 3161, 2547, 3068, 2739, 3936, 3290, 
2465, 2839, 2139, 2635, 1655, 3903, 2333, 1787, 2913, 2764, 2791, 
1501, 2101, 3312, 3428, 3502, 1826, 3823, 3064, 2705, 1917, 1427, 
1627, 1519, 3811, 3661, 3034, 1977, 2502, 3240, 1575, 2882, 3651, 
2065, 2366, 2016, 2991, 1996), School = c("Nursing", "Business", 
"Comm", "Nursing", "Business", "Nursing", "Nursing", "Nursing", 
"Nursing", "Nursing", "IR", "Comm", "Nursing", "IR", "Nursing", 
"Comm", "Business", "Business", "Business", "Nursing", "Nursing", 
"Nursing", "Comm", "Nursing", "Business", "Nursing", "Comm", 
"Business", "IR", "IR", "Nursing", "Business", "Business", "IR", 
"Business", "Business", "Business", "Comm", "Nursing", "Comm", 
"IR", "Nursing", "Nursing", "Nursing", "Nursing", "Comm", "Nursing", 
"Business", "IR", "Comm", "Comm", "Business", "IR", "Nursing", 
"Nursing", "IR", "Comm", "Business", "IR", "IR", "Nursing", "IR", 
"Nursing", "Nursing", "Nursing", "Business", "Comm", "Nursing", 
"IR", "IR", "Business", "Comm", "IR", "Nursing", "Nursing", "Business", 
"Nursing", "Comm", "Business", "Business", "Nursing", "Nursing", 
"Nursing", "Nursing", "Nursing", "Nursing", "Comm", "Nursing", 
"IR", "Business", "Nursing", "Comm", "Nursing", "Comm", "Nursing", 
"Nursing", "IR", "Business", "Nursing", "Comm")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Have you mixed `count` and `unique` column in your output table?

Comment: Please share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @TarJae I'm not sure I understand, are you saying that I mixed them up in my explanation?

Comment: @deschen added more information. Please let me know if that clarifies

Comment: Please don’t share your data as a table. Use dput!

Comment: @deschen shared as dput(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything in one pipe, but it doesn‘t necessarily look cleaner:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  count(School, name = 'count') %>%
  left_join(., data %>%
                 group_by(School) %>%
                 summarize(unique = n_distinct(ID)),
            by = 'School')
```

which gives with your example data:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  School   count unique
  <chr>    <int>  <int>
1 Business    22     22
2 Comm        18     18
3 IR          17     17
4 Nursing     43     43
```

I guess/assume it‘s just coincidence of your example data that there are no duplicate IDs per school and hence the count and unique value are the same.

Comment: This is exactly it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We could use `left_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df, df1, by="School")
```

```
    School count unique
1     Comm    42     17
2       IR    52     18
3 Business    34     14
4  Nursing    23     12
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without creating new dataframes? Counting occurrence of each school and distinct count of ID by school?